# Firebase App Distribution - iOS - Accounting

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution

Is it correct if an apple user gets an invitation from firebase app distribution he needs a google account to join the tester group?

Any suggestions to used it without a google account?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Google Account, you automatically get a Gmail address.

But if testers do not have a G suite or gmail address or if they would rather use another email address to sign in, you can link a non-Gmail email address to the account and use it to sign in, recover your password, get notifications, and more.

When choosing an alternate email, follow these requirements:

- You can't use a Gmail address.
- You can't use an email address that's already linked to another Google Account.
- Remember to use your Google Account password when signing in using this email address.

See the link: [Official Google Sign-in details](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

1 Click “Sign in with Google”
2 Select “Use another account” or “Create account”
3 In the Create your Google Account dialog, select the option “Use my current email address instead”
4 Create your account linked to your current email address and confirm your account

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no at this time, i got reponse from firebase/google support and they said you need to have google account. Yes, you can create it based on your current email not connected with google which is very simple, however this necessity forced my company to pursue alternatives. Imagine you have 500 testers and none have gmail account, some of them might not want to create it

Comment: This is exactly the same thing I have to deal with now. What alternatives are you evaluating?

Comment: Our testers were able to download a build by signing in with an "outlook" and company email on two different iPads. On both iPads we just followed the emails sent by Firebase. First email was about setting up the "Firebase App Distribution" configuration profile. Second email was about the specific build which has a button "Download the latest build". Have you tried to download a build to your iOS device?

Comment: @Lingo we are actually on the searching phase, but after going through some of the alternatives, we highly consider simply testflight as the iOS option. The thing with firebase now after acquired by google besides necessity of having g-account is that it has many dependencies that you have to integrate within your app, so to put in crashlytics for example there are additional google-environments dependencies, so we probably also drop crashlytics for that reason.

Comment: @OnurKeskin the emails we've received have just `Sign in with Google` button, there is no other visible options, so your testers might have created google accounts based on their own emails, and not aware of it

Comment: That was indeed true, they have created google accounts with their current emails some time ago without letting us know about it. Seems like google is just forcing users to having a google account.